# How to make Mac Terminal prompt and command bold?

Tags: macos, terminal

I want to make the prompt (and command, if possible) bold.

So if I do all these commands:

```
username$ ls
*lists a bunch of things*
username$ mkdir testdir
username$ ls
*lists a bunch of things*
```

I want the

```
username$ ls
username$ mkdir testdir
username$ ls
```

to all appear in bold, or at least the `username$` to appear in bold. Simply because it is hard when I am scrolling through the terminal to know when a new command is executed and stuff.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The prompt part (`username$`) is controlled by the `PS1` shell variable. You can have that variable changed by any init script like so:

```
export PS1="\[\e[1m\]$PS1\[\e[0m\]"
```

The `1` in there encodes "bold" and the `0` at the end is "reset". If you didn't put a reset in there, then the rest of the line would also be affected, but so would *any* text after it be, which is probably not what you're looking for.

You can add more styles and colours by separating codes with a semicolon like so:

```
export PS1="\[\e[1;5;31m\]$PS1\[\e[0m\]"
```

The basic codes can be enumerated with a simple one-liner:

```
for x in $(seq 0 255); do printf "\x1b[${x}m${x}\x1b[0m\n"; done
```

For more info, see [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code).

The `\[` and `\]` in there are not part of ANSI codes though, but are specific to `PS1`: they tell bash that the characters in between are non-printing, which it important e.g. to calculate line wrapping. See [bash prompt escape sequences](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/bash-prompt-escape-sequences.html).

Comment: Note: if you do fancy things like this with your prompt and then find that you get weird redraw glitches when e.g. you use command history or long commands wrap to a second line, then you need to double-check that you have `\[ \]` around *all* of the non-printing parts of the prompt, and *none* of the printing parts. Getting those wrong is a really common mistake, but if you get those right everything should work.